# Alloy tutorial, disconnected filesystem?

Tags: alloy

I'm working through the Alloy tutorial and am just starting [this chapter](http://alloy.mit.edu/alloy/tutorials/online/frame-FS-6.html).  My question is with the phrase that starts the chapter:

> Now that we've built a model that ensures the structural correctness of our file system ...

When I run the model built so far I still get disconnected file systems, which seems to contradict this phrase.

[image: Disconnected file system]

This is with Alloy 4.2, build date 2012-9-25 downloaded from the website a few days ago.  Am I doing something wrong or is this intentional?  From my understanding I don't see anything in the model that prevents disconnects like this.  But my understanding is still a bit fuzzy.

The relevant model is copied below:
 
`// File system objects
abstract sig FSObject { }
sig File, Dir extends FSObject { }`

// A File System
sig FileSystem {
  live: set FSObject,
  root: Dir & live,
  parent: (live - root) ->one (Dir & live),
  contents: Dir -> FSObject
}{
  // live objects are reachable from the root
  live in root.*contents
  // parent is the inverse of contents
  parent = ~contents
}

I could see the `live: set FSObject` line possibly requiring connection, but that's not my current understanding of the semantics of that line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I take the tutorial's remark about structural correctness to mean that the model ensures the properties:

- The filesystem root has no parent.
- Every live object is reachable from the root via the contents relation.
- The parent relation is the inverse of the contents relation.
- Every object reachable from the root is live.
- The contents and parent relations hold only on live objects.  (Objects that aren't live have no parent and no contents.)

In the instance you show, note that Dir0 is not live, has no contents, and has no parent.  So I think the instance obeys all the constraints I listed, and the file system (the tree rooted in Dir3) is in fact connected.  Dir0 is not a counter-example and not a structural problem with the file system; it's just a file-system object that is not reachable from any file system root and thus not live.  True?

Note that while the constraints do ensure that each FileSystem is a connected graph (a tree, in fact), they do not ensure that the file systems are connected to each other (nor that they are disjoint).  This should be easier to see if you change the run command to ask for multiple file systems.

You might be able to get a good bar discussion going at an IETF meeting over whether these constraints constitute "structural correctness" for file systems in general, but I think in context the phrase is just intended to point back to what was done in lessons I and II of the file system example.

Comment: Good point.  A comment in lesson II had led me to believe that the constraints developed to the point eliminated disconnected elements.  I see now that the comment was directed at eliminating disconnected elements from the contents relation.  Thanks!

Comment: Actually the tutorial goes on and fixes this with `live = root.*contents`